# Changing link to image using J Query dynamically

Tags: jquery, html

In the code below I'm trying to change the images in a dynamic way. that works fine however I would like to change the link that connects to each image dynamic too but I'm not quite sure how to get that to work

```js
$(function() {
  var dataArray = new Array();
  dataArray[0] = "img1.jpg";
  dataArray[1] = "img2.jpg";
  dataArray[2] = "img3.jpg";
  dataArray[3] = "img4.jpg";
  dataArray[4] = "img5.jpg";

  var thisId = 0;

  window.setInterval(function() {
    $('#charityimgSizer').attr('src', dataArray[thisId]);
    thisId++;
    if (thisId == 5) thisId = 0;
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="imageLink3" href="www.link4.com">
  <img id="charityimgSizer" src="img4.jpg" style="width: 300px" class="rewardImgSize alignright notopmargin pulse animated" alt="hexagon" title="hexagon" data-animate="pulse">
</a>
```

I would like some help with above, please. For example, how can I change the link on `$('#imageLink3')` to href `link2.com` when it's image is `img2.jpg`

Comment: I would suggest it's easier to have 5 distinct links/images, and show/hide as appropriate (rather than changing a single link/image)

Comment: As freefaller suggests, it may be worth loading the images up and simply cycling their visibility (Assuming there aren't a huge number of images) As well as being simpler and possible with no JS at all (just CSS) this lets the browser load the images ready to be displayed. So there will be no no flash of white space as each new image loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `a` tag (the way you did for the `img`) and use `.attr('href', '...')` to set the link url.

```js
$(function() {
  var dataArray = new Array();
  dataArray[0] = "img1.jpg";
  dataArray[1] = "img2.jpg";
  dataArray[2] = "img3.jpg";
  dataArray[3] = "img4.jpg";
  dataArray[4] = "img5.jpg";

  var thisId = 0;

  window.setInterval(function() {
    // add this
    $('#imageLink3').attr('href', grabLinkFromSomewhere());
    $('#charityimgSizer').attr('src', dataArray[thisId]);
    thisId++;
    if (thisId == 5) thisId = 0;
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="imageLink3" href="www.link4.com">
  <img id="charityimgSizer" src="img4.jpg" style="width: 300px" class="rewardImgSize alignright notopmargin pulse animated" alt="hexagon" title="hexagon" data-animate="pulse">
</a>
```

For example

```js
$(function() {
  var dataArray = new Array();
  dataArray[0] = "img1.jpg";
  dataArray[1] = "img2.jpg";
  dataArray[2] = "img3.jpg";
  dataArray[3] = "img4.jpg";
  dataArray[4] = "img5.jpg";
  
  const links = [
    'https://stackoverflow.com?id=1',
    'https://stackoverflow.com?id=2',
    'https://stackoverflow.com?id=3',
    'https://stackoverflow.com?id=4',
    'https://stackoverflow.com?id=5',
  ];

  var thisId = 0;

  window.setInterval(function() {
    // add this
    $('#imageLink3').attr('href', links[thisId]);
    $('#charityimgSizer').attr('src', dataArray[thisId]);
    thisId++;
    if (thisId == 5) thisId = 0;
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="imageLink3" href="www.link4.com">
  <img id="charityimgSizer" src="img4.jpg" style="width: 300px" class="rewardImgSize alignright notopmargin pulse animated" alt="hexagon" title="hexagon" data-animate="pulse">
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic to change the `href` of the link is similar to that you already have which changes the `src` of the `img`, as you can see in the example below. One thing to note is the use of `prop()` over `attr()`, though.

The main change I'd suggest would be to create an array of objects which you can fill with two properties, one for the `href` and one for the `src`. Then you can simply loop through them as the timeout is called. Try this:

```js
$(function() {
  var dataArray = [{
    img: "img1.jpg",
    url: 'link1.com'
  },{
    img: "img2.jpg",
    url: 'link2.com'
  },{
    img: "img3.jpg",
    url: 'link3.com'
  },{
    img: "img4.jpg",
    url: 'link4.com'
  },{
    img: "img5.jpg",
    url: 'link5.com'
  }]
  
  var thisId = 0;
  updateImageAndLink();
  window.setInterval(updateImageAndLink, 3000);

  function updateImageAndLink() {
    var obj = dataArray[thisId % dataArray.length];
    $('#charityimgSizer').prop('src', obj.img);
    $('#imageLink3').prop('href', obj.url);
    thisId++;  
  }
});
```

```css
#charityimgSizer {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="imageLink3" href="">
  <img id="charityimgSizer" src="" class="rewardImgSize alignright notopmargin pulse animated" alt="hexagon" title="hexagon" data-animate="pulse">
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not only use your ID when iterating and constructing everything on the fly.

For Example

```
var thisId = 0;

window.setInterval(function() {
    // add this
    $('#imageLink' + thisId).attr('href', 'www.link' + thisId + '.com');
    $('#charityimgSizer').attr('src', dataArray[thisId]);
    thisId++;
    if (thisId == 5) thisId = 0;
  }, 3000);
```

As every selector is just a plain string you can manipulate/concat it just other strings

I would even suggest to give the image a source string url to to resources directly and only changing the id iteself, if u don't need to rely on the images coming from an external source later and being loaded into `dataArray`

e.g.

```
$('#charityimgSizer').attr('src', 'path/to/img' + thisId + '.jpg');
```